# Django DisallowedModelAdminLookup for lookup in Admin list_filter

Tags: python, django

I have a `Member` model and an `Organization` model, joined via a `PrincipleMembership` model. `PrincipleMembership` has `ForeignKey` fields for `Member` and `Organization`.

I create `MemberAdmin` with the line `list_filter = ['principlemembership__organization__type', ]`, the filter renders perfectly, but clicking on it produces the `DisallowedModelAdminLookup` exception.

I can fix it by overriding `ModelAdmin.Lookup_allowed` to permit `principlemembership__organization__type__exact`, but is this a bug in Django? I'm on Python 3.5.3 and Django 1.10.

I have tried adding filters on `organization.type` to `OrganizationAdmin` and `PrincipleMembershipAdmin`, both of which work. I do not use a many to many join as I have other data on `PrincipleMembership`, such as `From` and `To` dates. I have tried making the filter explicitly a `admin.ChoicesFieldListFilter`. I have tried removing everything else from `MemberAdmin` except `list_filter = ['principlemembership__organization__type', ]`. I have tried a filter on a simple Char field on `Organization` and get the same error.

Comment: Still same issue in Django 2.2.5 also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug, fixed in 1.11.3. See the change in this commit:
https://github.com/django/django/commit/834d57b4de80e525195128c88592e0e076708a23

The [1.11.3 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11.3/) have a link to the [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28262).

Comment: I could reproduce the same problem on 1.11.8. I need to fix it by using `ModelAdmin.lookup_allowed` in the meantime.